# Hover over li not displying div

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have ol in my header of the page. In last two there is an Username and profile pic. And I want to show dropdown menu on hover over username or profile pic. But it is not displaying menu on hover. There is one lebel inside my dropdown-content.In mozilla it is not showing anything on hover and in chrome it is also not showing on hover but by default it is showing label.

```css
.head{
    top:0;
    background:#424242;
    padding:1px;
    height:10%;
}
li{
     display:inline-block;
     color:#E0E0E0;
     cursor:pointer;
     padding:10px 10px 2px 10px;
     font-size:20px;
}
li:hover{
    color:white;
}
li.active{
    color:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    
}
.right{
    float:right;
    color:white;
}
#profilepic{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin:-10px 50px 0 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 150px;
    right:0;
    margin-right:20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content label {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content label:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.right:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="head">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li onClick="NewApplication();">NEW APPLICATION</li>
                <li onClick="PendingApplication();">PENDING APPLICATION</li>
                <li onClick="Customer();">APPROVED</li>
                <li>LOAN STRUCTURE</li>
                <li class="right"><img id="profilepic" src="images/emp2.jpg"></li>
                <li class="right">ABC</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <label onClick="Setting();">SETTINGS</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue

Comment: You would need javascript or jQuery for this. CSS cannot reference parent selectors.

Comment: `.dropdown-content` is not a descendant of `.right` so your selector `.right:hover .dropdown-content` is incorrect.

Comment: ok i got it and solved it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please restructure your html like so, this will be ideal for showing the dropdown.

The below class will be used to show  the hidden dropdown.

```
.show-settings:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  color: black;
  position:relative;
}

#profilepic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -10px 50px 0 20px;
}

.show-settings:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 150px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content label {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content label:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li onClick="NewApplication();">NEW APPLICATION</li>
    <li onClick="PendingApplication();">PENDING APPLICATION</li>
    <li onClick="Customer();">APPROVED</li>
    <li>LOAN STRUCTURE</li>
    <li class="right show-settings">
      <img id="profilepic" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50"> username
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <label onClick="Setting();">SETTINGS</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: not working in chrome

Comment: @user10184882 Chrome version?

Comment: Ok now my edit also working and ur code too. It was cache problem.

Comment: @user10184882 Oh ok

Answer (score 0):

Putting space between two CSS selctors (`.class1 .class2`), specify that you want a hirarchy - when `.class2` is nested inside `class1`. You can't by CSS only to get the parent of an element. So, to solve your problem, you should do it by js, or including `.dropdown-content` inside the `<ul>` element (change it from `<div>` to `<li>`, because inside lists only `<li>` elements are valid), and then access it by [CSS3's general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors) (or by [CSS3's adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors), I don't use it here):

**Solution 1:**

```css
.right {
  float: right;
}

#profilepic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -10px 50px 0 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 150px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content label {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content label:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.right:hover ~ .dropdown-content, /* or ".right:hover + .dropdown-content" with adjacent sibling selector */
.dropdown-content:hover /* For the dropdown won't disappear when hover it */ {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li onClick="NewApplication();">NEW APPLICATION</li>
    <li onClick="PendingApplication();">PENDING APPLICATION</li>
    <li onClick="Customer();">APPROVED</li>
    <li>LOAN STRUCTURE</li>
    <li class="right"><img id="profilepic" src="images/emp2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="right">ABC</li>
    <li class="dropdown-content">
      <label onClick="Setting();">SETTINGS</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.right').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      dropdown.style.display = 'block';
    }, false);
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      dropdown.style.display = 'none';
    }, false);
  });
};
```

```css
.right {
  float: right;
}

#profilepic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -10px 50px 0 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 150px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content label {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content label:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li onClick="NewApplication();">NEW APPLICATION</li>
                <li onClick="PendingApplication();">PENDING APPLICATION</li>
                <li onClick="Customer();">APPROVED</li>
                <li>LOAN STRUCTURE</li>
                <li class="right"><img id="profilepic" src="images/emp2.jpg"></li>
                <li class="right">ABC</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <label onClick="Setting();">SETTINGS</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Its not working in chrome

Comment: @user10184882 Solution 1 or 2?

Comment: @user10184882 I fixed an issue with Solution 2.